# Logging only a specific part of stderr?

Tags: stderr

Couldn't find anything on this, but I'm trying to only log a specific part of stderr to a file. So for example

Running `tar -xzf file 2>> log.txt`, and getting an error

```
tar: Child returned status 1
```

I only want to log the Child returned status 1 part, and not include the command name.

Comment: You would have to filter stderr through some process. However, removing the process name removes vital debugging info, so I would not do that.

Comment: Do you want to remove the `tar: ` prefix off every error message by `tar`, or just that one and discard every other error message by both `tar` and `gzip`?

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -xzf file 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -oP '^app: \K.*$' | tee logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
tar -xzf file 2> >(sed 's/^tar: //' >> file.log)
```

Which allows to retain `tar`'s exit status.

You can do something similar with `ksh`, `bash` or `yash` though [you'd have to use work arounds there to make sure `sed` has finished by the time you run the next command if that command makes use of the `file.log`](/a/388530).

Other option with `bash` is to use:

```
{ tar -xzf file 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | sed 's/^tar: //' >> file.log 3>&-; } 3>&1
tar_exit_status=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Note that with several shells, you can also call `tar` with an empty argv[0] with:

```
(exec -a '' tar -xzf file)
```

In which case the error messages will look like:

```
: Child returned status 1
```